# Can Not connect to Remote SQL server named instance with port

Tags: sql-server-2005, connection, port, named-instance

Hi All We have a server where we have sql server 2008 as well as SQL server 2005 hosted on port 1444. Using SSMS, I am able to connect to 2008 instance without any problem. But when I try to connect to 2005 instance using following connection settings.

DEVDB1\SQL_2005,1444
SQL server authentication user name and password.

I get following error

> "A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while
>   establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or
>   was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that
>   SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: TCP
>   Provider, error: 0 - A Connection attempt failed because the connected
>   party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established
>   connection failed because connection host has failed to
>   respond)(Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 10060)"

I am able to connect to another instance on the same server. but not this.

NOTE: My colleagues are able to connect to this sql server with the same settings. It just does not work from my machine. Me and all my colleagues are working on VPN and have same machine configuration.

Is there any setting that I need to do/check to get successfully connected?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My VPN user profile was restricting access to this perticular port. Once my VPN user profile is matched with those who were able to access, the problem resolved.